# Calculate average of values

Tags: algorithms

I'm building a rating system where users can cast votes between 1-5. I store the values in a PHP array like this:

```
array(
    '1' => 99,
    '2' => 11,
    '3' => 0,
    '4' => 8123,
    '5' => 522,
);
```

So, `522` people voted `5`.

My question is, how do I calculate the total average of this when putting all the votes together? So we end up with one value like:

```
Total rating: 4.2
```

**The total rating should never exceed `5`.** What's the algorithm for this?

Comment: I understand this may be entry-level stuff to maths. =)

Comment: I usually just consider that to be a special case of arithmetic mean, but it seems to be called a [weighed arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average).

Comment: You should explain why simply taking the average (arithmetic mean) is not ideal.  As @N.Bach notes, the values $1$ to $5$ are "weighted" by the number of votes, and this average will never be greater than the largest value $5$ (or less than the smallest value $1$).  You can also choose a rounding rule for display, e.g. round to the nearest tenth  or a variation on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average (arithmetic mean) is calculated by
$$
\frac{ \left(1 \times 99\right) + \left(2 \times 11\right)  + \left(3 \times 0\right) + \left(4\times 8123\right) + \left(5\times 522\right)}{99 + 11  + 0 + 8123 + 522}
$$
which I calculate to be approximately $4.023$

Comment: I got the value at `4.2274363898224` which not near `4.023`

Comment: Also,  '1' => 1, '2' => 1,  '3' => 1, '4' => 1, '5' => 522  gives `524` as total average. It should never go above `5`

Comment: $$\dfrac{(1 \times 1) +(2 \times 1) +(3 \times 1) +(4 \times 1) +(5 \times 522)}{1+1+1+1+522} = 4.980988593 <5.$$

Comment: My bad, it does work. One final issue though. If all vote values are set to 0, then I get a `Division by zero` error.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You can't average something if there are 0 participant. So this is both undefined on the mathematical level, and doesn't make sense intuitively.

Comment: I understand, but is it mathematically possible to allow a scenario where all the votes are set to 0 and we won't receive an error?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Just check the total number of vote beforehand and perform "control flow". If there are no participant don't compute the mean. Since you mentionned php, you may want to display something specific on the web page to indicate there are no votes though.